# Home automation

Tags: home-directory, automation

I've been using a Windows program 'Active Home' to run my X10 gear.

I've recently changed computers, and my new system will not run Windows XP, which is the only program that this will run on.

Does anyone know of a similar program that will run on Ubuntu?

Comment: Investigate `bottlerocket` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/bottlerocket

Comment: Homeassistant runs well on Ubuntu and includes X10 integration.

Comment: You could set up a VirtualBox guest running Windows XP, and then try and run Active Home that way. How are you connecting X10 devices to the computer... through a serial port, or a USB to serial port adapter?

Comment: Thank you I've tried that but Windows XP does not connect with a USB when used in Virtual Box (which is required to run Active home) So I get no further with that unless you can help me with that problem as well

Comment: Home assistant sounds good but I can't quite seem to get it to work on my machine. I really appreciate the help but I'm not getting anywhere with it. If someone could point me in the right direction with step by step instructions it would be wonderful.

Comment: Heynnema, I use CM15 Pro connected to a USB slot on my computer. My program used to run mainly from that although I do have two remote controls that work through that as well.